# Can I grow asparagus in a small container?

Tags: vegetables, containers, asparagus

I have read countless times that asparagus cannot be harvested in the first two years. I do not own my property so do not want to invest that time into something I leave behind.

Are there any gotchas around growing asparagus in something small and movable, should I need to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Asparagus roots can extend down about 12 feet. The need to develop such an extensive root system is one of the reasons that you should leave it alone for the first 3 years before harvesting. So, it's not practical to grow asparagus in containers.